# exit code error after lint in deno workflow github actions

Tags: github-actions, cicd, deno

for a some reason after:

```yaml
- name: Run linter
        run: deno lint
```

I get error that says Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

my workflow github action file:

```yaml
name: Deno tests

on: [push, pull_request]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Setup repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Deno
        # uses: denoland/setup-deno@v1
        uses: denoland/setup-deno@61fe2df320078202e33d7d5ad347e7dcfa0e8f31  # v1.1.2
        with:
          deno-version: v1.x

      # Uncomment this step to verify the use of 'deno fmt' on each commit.
      # - name: Verify formatting
      #   run: deno fmt --check

      - name: Run linter
        run: deno lint

      - name: Run tests
        run: deno test -A
```

https://github.com/Rnbsov/Omnivore-Telegram-Bot/actions/runs/8129066025/job/22215706030

##### What I tried:

to fix it I tried to add `1` to this

```yaml
  name: Run linter
     run: deno lint || 1
```

but after this I started getting error

```bash
/home/runner/work/_temp/96e6eec7-6bd6-4a3c-91a1-db6b0cd9c993.sh: line 1: 1: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

https://github.com/Rnbsov/Omnivore-Telegram-Bot/actions/runs/8153916055/job/22286236020

Comment: Apparently your code failed linting. Why do you _want_ the job to pretend it succeeded?

Comment: Thanks a lot Teemu Risikko, that's what I was searching for

but speaking of johnsharpe, yeah it might be better to create a separete action for linting and test will do this

thanks guys